# Нужен загрузчик mp3 файлов на сайт с полосой состояния загрузки.

Tags: php, upload, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Мне нужен загрузчик файлов на сайт, но не uploadify - что-то он х*во работает... кто может помочь? естественно за небольшую плату...

Comment: Как может "х*во" работать компонент, который всего-то берет файл и отправляет его на сервер? Тут, похоже, дело не в uploadify

Comment: Если не кроссбраузерно и на клиенте http://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-onprogress  .На сервере это делается через механизм сессий http://php.net/manual/ru/session.upload-progress.php  (если разберетесь помогите и мне)

Comment: в том то и дело, что uploadify выдает какую-то свою неведомую ошибку уже и увеличил размер заливаемого файла через PHP и что только не делал... все равно грузит до 15% первый раз прерывается, второй раз на 15% выдает ошибку IO Error - и что с ней делать не понятно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать:

- [FileAPI](https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI/) — html5 + flash (NativeJS)
- [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) — только современные браузеры (jQuery/jQueryUI)
- [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) — html5 + flash + silverlight (NativeJS)